# Efficiently manage same code for single element or array of elements

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a large class with many methods. This class has a subclass that manages a different situation.

Just to clear it up with an example the actual situation is the following:

```
class Logic {
public:
  virtual void method()
  {
    Something::getInstance()->doSomething();
  }
};

class ArrayLogic : public Logic {
private:
  Something** array;

public:
  void method() override
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; ++i)
      array[i]->doSomething();
  }
};
```

Now this pattern repeats itself in multiple methods and I'd like to have just one implementation without trading for performance (since some of this methods are actually already proven to require efficiency).

I was thinking if it's possible with C++11 to have a template solution approach which is able to manage this situation at compile time without the necessity to duplicate the code.

Mind that the `array` doesn't make sense to exist for `Logic` so having a `Something*[1]` is not a viable option.

An additional problem is that at the moment `Something**` array is not directly contained in `ArrayLogic` but resides in another class, so it's more like

```
class ArrayLogic : public Logic {
private:
  Container* container;

public:
  void method() override {
    for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; ++i)
      if (container->array[i])
        container->array[i]->doSomething();
  }
}
```

While having to check for `container->array[i] != nullptr` may seems strange the fact is that the position is relevant, so an element removed from the array doesn't cause a shift of the successive element but leaves a hole.

Comment: @quantdev: yes, forgot to add it while typing the example, thanks.

Comment: Where does `AMOUNT` come from? Is it a constant by any chance?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: at the moment yes, of course having it modifiable (like having a `std::vector<Something*> array` would be nice but it's not a strict requirement just a better potential solution.

Comment: From the example, it looks like `Logic::method` should just be a free function which takes a `Something*`, analogous to STL's algorithm and container separation. Is there a performance based reason to stick to this design?

Comment: "Now this pattern repeats itself in multiple methods". It's not clear from your post which pattern you are talking about. Is it the base class derived class relationship? Is it the `for` loop in the derived class?

Comment: Why not use higher-order function (a bit like `std::transform`) with a lambda?

Comment: @Pradhan: the rationale behind this is that the `Logic` manages the game logic for a game while `ArrayLogic` manages the game logic for the same game during multiplayer (so things are called on multiple players). The whole other part of the engine doesn't want/need to know how the logic is internally managed, since the fact that the logic is handling multiple players should be hidden to the rest. At the same time performance for single-player `Logic` shouldn't be affected at all since most of these methods are called continuously.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try and create separate classes for single and multiplayer games. Base both of these on a base class `LogicBase` that has a `method(Something*)` function that calls `doSomething()` on its parameter. This is what @Pradhan was referring to.

In your main game, you can use a `LogicBase*` to refer to either a `SinglePlayerLogic` or a `MultiPlayerLogic` object and call the relevant `method()` using a virtual function call.

I'm passing what is stored in `Container` to the constructor of `MultiPlayerLogic`. But it could be in a separate class and accessed that way. Similarly, it may be cleaner to pass a `Something` to the constructor of `SinglePlayerLogic`, but I wanted to keep the code structure close to your original, so didn't do this.

It initially looks funny for `LogicBase` to call to a subclass, then have those subclasses call the protected `method(Something*)` back in the super class. I've seen it elsewhere as a design pattern, but can't recall it's name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int AMOUNT = 5;

struct Something {
    void doSomething() { std::cout << "Something::doSomething\n"; }

    static Something* getInstance() { static Something s; return &s; }
};

class LogicBase {
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;

protected:
    void method(Something* s) { s->doSomething(); }
};

class SinglePlayerLogic : public LogicBase {
public:
    void method() override
    {
        std::cout << "SinglePlayer::method\n";
        LogicBase::method(Something::getInstance());
    }
};

class MultiPlayerLogic : public LogicBase {
public:
    MultiPlayerLogic(Something **s) : players(s) {}

    void method() override
    {
        std::cout << "MultiPlayer::method\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; ++i) {
            if (players[i] == nullptr) {
                continue;
            }

            std::cout << i << " ";
            LogicBase::method(players[i]);
        }
    }

private:
    Something** players;
};

int main() {
    LogicBase* lb;

    SinglePlayerLogic spl;

    lb = &spl;
    lb->method();

    std::vector<Something*> players{AMOUNT};
    MultiPlayerLogic mpl(players.data());

    lb = &mpl;
    lb->method();
}
```